# How to get a business class property value in jquery variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to get a business class property value to a java script variable. Using that value iam doing some manipulations. Here I have tried by creating object and string in the aspx page but I was unable to acess the string "val" in Java script. How to access it ?

**Aspx File:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<% WebApplication1.Business obj = new WebApplication1.Business(); %>
<% string val = obj.Name; %>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        alert("welcome");
            var valProperty = <%= val%>;
            alert("Val Property is :   "+ valProperty);
            $("#txtName").val(valProperty);
           });
        });
    </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <input type="text" id="txtName" />
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Get Server Property Value" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Class File:**

```
 public class Business
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Money { get; set; }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're accessing it just fine, you just haven't set the obj.Name

```
<% WebApplication1.Business obj = new WebApplication1.Business(); %>
// assign something to obj.Name here
<% string val = obj.Name; %>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use it like this:

```
var valProperty = <%= val%>;
```

then you'll need a public class field on the ASPX page like this:

```
public string val = null;
```

that you then set later.

Comment: if i set public to the string it's throwing error like "Invalid Expression term Public"

Comment: @Vignesh, note it says **public class field**. You need to define the field in the class, or code-behind file.

Answer (score 0):

add quotes:

```
var valProperty = "<%= val%>";
```

and don't forget to assign something to obj.Name

Comment: Iam getting empty value for valProperty if use the above code

Comment: cause you did not assign anything to obj.Name

Comment: and you did not defined setter and getter for the property